# Lagrangian relaxation Cplex & Java

Tags: java, cplex

I have a composed objective function for solving the lagrangian relaxation of a problem (p).

The mathematical formulation of the objective function is :

```
Minimize [sum(i in n) time[i] * poids[i] + sum (i in n) Mult[i]* ((sum (j in n) x[i][j]) -1).
```

I tried the folowing but does not work :

```
    // objective
    IloNumExpr expr1 = null;
    IloLinearNumExpr obj = cplex1.linearNumExpr();

    for (int i =0; i<n; i++) {
        obj.addTerm(time[i],W[i]);
    }


    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        IloLinearNumExpr expr = cplex1.linearNumExpr();
        for (int j=0; j<n; j++){
            if (cplex1.equals(x[i][j])){
                expr.addTerm(1,x[i][j]);
            }
        }  cplex1.sum(expr,-1);
           cplex1.prod(expr, mult[i]);  

         obj.add(expr); 
    }           

    cplex1.addMinimize(obj);
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple mistakes within your code.

I'm assuming here that `cplex1` is an `IloCplex` type variable.

That being said, you have

```
for (int j=0; j<n; j++){
            if (cplex1.equals(x[i][j])){
                expr.addTerm(1,x[i][j]);
            }
        }  cplex1.sum(expr,-1);
           cplex1.prod(expr, mult[i]);
```

This has two mistakes. First

```
if (cplex1.equals(x[i][j])){
```

You're comparing an `IloCplex` to a number variable. This will always return false. What were you trying to accomplish here?

Second mistake is that this

```
cplex1.sum(expr,-1);
cplex1.prod(expr, mult[i]);
```

Should be this

```
expr = cplex1.sum(expr,-1);
expr = cplex1.prod(expr, mult[i]);
```

Since the methods dont change their inputs, but return the result.

Try to change your mistakes and if you're still with problems. Try to post a more complete code snippet.

Hope this helps